# nginx location block to match url

Tags: nginx

I would like to route my requests using nginx in the following fashion

```
site.com/admin -> admin/index.html
                  admin/js/assets.js // the route locations have individual assets
site.com/112dw -> dist/index.html // alphanumeric regex
                  dist/css/assets.css
```

I have the following nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location /admin {
        //alias /usr/share/nginx/html/admin/;
        try_files $uri /admin/index.html; // changed based on answer below
    }
    location ~* /[a-zA-Z0-9].*$ { // rest of the routes
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        //alias /usr/share/nginx/html/dist/;
        try_files $uri /dist/index.html;
    }
}
```

After I changed my config to use try_files, my static assets are not being served as the HTML is searching for path one directory above. Could anyone point me to set this up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to accomplish this is by using `try_files`:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location =/admin {
    try_files /admin/index.html =404;
}
location ~*^/[a-z0-9]+$ {
    try_files /dist/index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: my static files are not being served with this method. html is searching html/js instead of html/dist/js

Comment: would this require me to configure all the folders for static files separately? the html requests are being sent without the dist in request so all the js requests are failing. I am sorry if this is a noob question .. I am new to nginx and trying to make sense of the config.

Comment: @PavanK There are no "js" requests in your question, and the configuration above is written only to serve these two types of requests you have provided. You should update your question with the full list of requirements.

Comment: The second location did not work. The route is going to index.html in the html folder.  The location doesn't change. I am still trying to configure but I have accepted this answer as I could atleast get one part

Comment: @PavanK Could you clarify how the `site.com/112dw` request needs to be mapped to `dist/css/assets.css`?

Comment: site.com/112dw needs to render dist/index.html. dist is a folder in /usr/share/nginx/html and dist contains index.html, css, js folders. I currently have root pointed to /usr/share/nginx/html/dist; I tried to change root in the admin location but the index.html is not being served from that location

Comment: I read from the docs that specifying root in location is bad practice but I am not sure how else to configure this

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`index`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index), [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) or [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) directive to point requests to `index.html`.

You do not need to use a regex location for the default. In fact, the way you have it defined in your question, the `/admin` location is never consulted.

You should use `root` rather than `alias` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)).

There are any number of solutions, probably depending on how your resource files should be resolved. Something like this pattern might work for your:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html/dist;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
location /admin {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /admin/index.html;
}
```

Comment: my static files are not being served with this method. html is searching html/js instead of html/dist/js